# Access kubernetes-dashboard using ingess ( 404 Not Found )

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm relatively new to k8s and was following an [tutorial](https://youtu.be/X48VuDVv0do) to get familiar with it. There was a example on exposing kubernetes-dashboard via ingress and I tried to try it.

Configured kubernetes-dashboard by running following. As per its [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/).
kubectl apply -f `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.6.1/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`

But different from the tutorial kubernetes-dashboard was exposed via port 443

```
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.108.119.138   <none>        8000/TCP   50m
service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.100.58.17     <none>        443/TCP    50m
```

So I changed the ingress configuration yaml accordingly.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  name: ingress-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec: 
  rules:
  - host: k8s-dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 443
```

Then I describe the ingress and get the ip and added an entry in /etc/hosts for it

```
kubectl describe ingress ingress-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
Name:             ingress-dashboard
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        kubernetes-dashboard
Address:          192.168.49.2
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host               Path  Backends
  ----               ----  --------
  k8s-dashboard.com  
                     /   kubernetes-dashboard:443 (172.17.0.6:8443)
Annotations:         kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    24m (x2 over 25m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

/etc/hosts change

```
192.168.49.2    k8s-dashbaord.com
```

When tried to access k8s-dashbaord.com. I get a 404 Not Found from nginx. So it seems like ingress is running but it cannot reach the service.

The ip mapped to ingress rule seems to be wrong though. (172.17.0.6:8443). Because that is not the ip of the service.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S

If I just to a proxy ( kubectl proxy ) and access dashboard it works fine.

Comment: what port number is the POD exposed ? And when you run `kubectl proxy` are you accessing thru `http` or `https` ?

Comment: @Bala Pod is exposing `443`. From `Kubectl prosy` access is via `http`.

Comment: Hi @SusithaRavindaSenarath can you check whether this [blog](https://jonathangazeley.com/2020/09/16/exposing-the-kubernetes-dashboard-with-an-ingress/) will help or not

Comment: @SusithaRavindaSenarath, did you figure this out? I am running into the same issue using aws-alb-ingress-controller.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh No, couldn't get it to work. I could use `minicube dashboard` to access the dashboard but couldn't really sort out to do it via exposing ingress.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the trailing "/" in your URL calling.
My ingress work fine :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
    name: kubernetes-dashboard-ingress
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
        - shared-kind-1-k8s.local
    secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-cert
  rules:
  - host: shared-kind-1-k8s.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dashboard(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 443
```